# max of a column in a numpy array in python

Tags: python

In Matlab you can do things such as

```
Mat1[: , end] = max( Value1 * (Mat2[:, end]-Value2 ),0)
```

I tried the equivalent in Python but i'm getting an error and i'm not sure why

```
Mat1[: , -1] = max( Value1 * (Mat2[:, -1]-Value2 ),0)
```

The error is below

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the python builtin method `max`, use `np.max` instead:

```
import numpy as np
Mat1[: , -1] = np.max( Value1 * (Mat2[:, -1]-Value2 ),0)
```

Comment: its the little things you forget at 4 am that make all the difference thanks

Comment: I'm sure I don't represent any majority